# Does IMAP downloads all Messages in Microsoft outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I have 3Gb mails on Gmail.
I used Microsoft Outlook 2007 for imap.

But the PST file is only 400MB. Isn't that supposed to be 3GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email clients typically have settings that you can configure to keep attachments on the server until requested, download only headers until a message is being read, etc.  You likely don't have Outlook set up to download the full contents of your mailbox right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP is intended to be a remote protocol.  By default it leaves messages on the server and manages them there.  There's options in Outlook to enable "offline" storage of email.